# Adding regressing equation to a scatter plot

Tags: d3.js, charts, regression, scatter-plot, c3.js

I have the following chart working:

```
var Grade_access = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#grade_access',
    data: {
        url: 'grades_access.csv',
        x: 'Access_grade',
        types: {
            Grade:'scatter',
            Regression: 'line'
        },
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
        label: {
            text: "Average grade",
            position: "outer-middle"
        },
        min: 1,
        max: 9
        },
        x: {
        label: {
            text: "Access grade PAU",
            position: "outer-center"
        },
        min: 9,
        max: 14
        }
    },
    size: {
        height: 400,
        width: 800
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'inset',
        inset: {
        anchor: 'top-right',
        x: 20,
        y: 300
        }
    }
})

document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = "Grade = " + 2 + "·x + " + 1;
```

grade_access.csv looks like this:

```
Access_grade,Chemistry I,Regression
9.85,3.8,4.54
10.64,5.0,5.31
10.0,4.0,4.69
10.92,5.4,5.58
11.69,5.5,6.33
11.79,8.0,6.43
11.03,6.3,5.69
10.47,5.0,5.14
10.1,5.6,4.78
12.13,8.5,6.76
11.94,6.4,6.57
10.96,6.7,5.62
10.45,5.9,5.12
10.45,5.7,5.12
12.62,7.7,7.24
10.19,5.0,4.87
```

But I want to change two things to improve it:

- Avoid the dots in blue being united with a line (I only want the orange dots united to create the regression line)
- Display the true equation of the regression line (now I made up the coeficients: 2 and 1 are not the real ones)

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just inspect the line `path` and hide using css? Also,changing `Grade` to `'Chemistry I'` will give you a scatter and then you dont have to explicitly hide it using css.

Comment: Thanks! But the name Chemistry I is changing name over time (dynamic csv file), do you know how can I refer to it as the second element of the first row without passing a name? @AdityaK

Comment: And any idea for displaying the regression? @AdityaK

Answer (score 1):

To hide the line connected the blue dots you can either inspect the `path` element and hide the class using css, or change the `Grade` to `Chemistry I`.

Since your regression values have already been calculated, it just makes calculating the coefficients very easy.

```
var d1 = data[0];
var d2 = data[1];
var b = (1-(d2['Regression']/d1['Regression']))/((d1['Access_grade']-d2['Access_grade'])/d1['Regression']);
var a = d1['Regression'] - (b * d1['Access_grade']);
```

I took the first two data points and then its just like solving a system of linear equations.

Here's your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6rhXyYIJuQe9BQ2HSOa9?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you! @AdityaK The regression looks good but I do not understand why the coeficients are negative if the line has positive slope... And also, I cannot change Grade into Chemistry I because Chemistry I is the title of the column in THIS csv but the csv will be changing over the time and I want the chart to read the title of the column by itself... Any idea?

Comment: @MTT do you know what the coefficients should be in this particular case? I don't know if what I calculated are correct.

Comment: I have calculated the correct coefficients already! A mathematical error only... Any help with how to access the name of the column that changes over time? (Chemistry I, Calculus I...)

Comment: What will it change to? Will the column name that changes have an `I` at the end?

Comment: not always... The different names that the column can have can be: Calculus I, Geometry, Calculus II, Chemistry I, Linear Algebra... The name always appears on the title of the second column of the csv file

Comment: Do you have any idea?